# Probability that the system works given two subsystems with series and parallel connections

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Consider the system of components connected as in the accompanying picture. Components $1$ and $2$ are connected in parallel, so that subsystem works iff either $1$ or $2$ works:
since $3$ and $4$ are connected in series, that subsystem works iff both $3$ and $4$ work. If components work independently of one another and $P$ (component $i$ works $)=.9$ for $i=1,2$ and $=.8$ for $i=3,4$, calculate $P$ (system works).

[image]

My try:
I actually calculated using complementary method. It is obvious that the system does not work in the following cases:

Case $1.$ If none of the components work

Case $2.$ If both $1,2$ does not work and $3$ works but $4$ does not.

Case $3.$ If both $1,2$ does not work and $4$ works but $3$ does not.

So the required probability is
$$P(\text{system works})=1-(0.1)^2(0.2)^2-2(0.1)^2(0.8)(0.2)=0.9964$$
But the book answer is $0.9981$

Comment: I think your calculation is right.  Here's an alternate way of doing it.  The probability that the parallel circuit works is $.9+.9-.9^2=.99$  The probability the the series circuit works is $.64.$  The probability that at least one circuit works is $.99+.64-.99*.64=.9964$

Comment: Ok thats nice thank you